# Install xSendFile in Apache Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, linux, apache, yii2, digital-ocean

I want to use the xSendFIle to download large files in PHP. I have tried following the tutorials here https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/ to get it installed.

I did this by 
1) Cloning the directory

`git clone https://github.com/nmaier/mod_xsendfile.git`

2) Installing it using

```
 apxs -cia mod_xsendfile.c
```

3) I edited my virtualhost port 80 to look like this

- `nano /etc/apache2/sites-available#000-default.conf`

`<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName example.com
   Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond https://example.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
    XSendFile on
    XSendFilePath /var/www/html/hostfolder/web/
</VirtualHost>`

At this point, I expected my download to work and download a file inside 
/var/www/html/hostfolder/web/music/file.zip

Extra information:
I am using Yii2 framework
I am hosting with Digital Ocean

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated

Comment: You are saying that you expect you file download to work, but what is currently happening, what does not work? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: No, It downloads 0bytes

Answer (score 6):

Why not just install the module using you native package manager instead:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-xsendfile
```

To see which modules are enabled you can do:

```
apache2 -M
```

The module should be enabled by default, but you can also enable it simply running:

```
sudo a2enmod xsendfile
```

Comment: e2enmod: command not found . Tried looking for how to install it but I don't get it

Comment: that was a typo error, a2enmod does not exist on I can't figure out how to resolve it

Comment: though I am also convinced the package is successly installed might be I have a problem with the configurations

Comment: what version of apache are you running

Comment: everything seems to be working well with the installation but the download isnt working. I still get 0byte when I try to download